# How to show date formats for any system formats in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, date

I am getting the date from api like `childDob: "25/06/2019"` and some like `25-06-2019` and i am using `type="date"` in html and `datePipe.transform()` in .ts class

sample code : [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbxwax?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

So i am able to show some dates for certain records and some aren't. So is there any possible way like any package in Angular to remove these issues i need to show any date format(whatever format it is) in my html. pls help.

FYI, i have used moment and datepipe.

TIA

Comment: Are these the only date formats you are going to get? `25/06/2019` or `25-06-2019` ?

Comment: You have to set the format first! - Either it could be `25/06/2019` or `25-06-2019` then convert/transform before rendering on the HTML

Comment: It's a standard to have a data contract with middleware on the format of data the front end receives and sends.

Comment: I am getting sometimes / and - formats to fit with every format is there any solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is one package which you can use i.e ng2-datepicker
ref-:https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datepicker

And irrespective of the format you receive, you can convert it into date like and convert it to date using

```
 let dateArray= this.receivedDate.split("/") // this.receivedDate.split("-"); 
 let convDate = new Date(dateArray[2],(dateArray[1]-1),dateArray[0]);
```

Comment: you can improve as `const dateArray=this.receivedDate.replace(/-/g,'/').split('/')`. (first replace all "-" by "/" and then split)